# what to use instead of c# event to have code easy to port to c++?

Tags: c#, events

I'm writing on C#.
I like using `event`. It's very natural for my classes to just publish event and don't care who and how will they process. However as I will need to migrate my code to c++ should I still use `event`? How easy would be to rewrite such code to c++? Probably it makes sense to use other technics that easier to rewrite to c++?

**upd** i've found similar question [C#-like events in C++, Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461093/c-like-events-in-c-composition)

Comment: C# and C++ are different enough that you will not be able to port easily, no matter what you do.  You should write idiomatic C# and worry about C++ separately.

Comment: sorry question is - what to use on c#. it's good to know what can I use on c++ though. will boost::signal completely replace c# event in straighforward manner?

Comment: You'll need to learn C++ from scratch.. you can't just convert c# code to c++.  Though - to make the concepts easier, you might want to think about keeping with Visual Studios, and just use Visual C++

Comment: @SLaks disagree, i think it's pretty possible to write code on C# that will be easy to port to C++. after all both of these languages are OOP languages.

Comment: @javapowered: Wrong.  Memory management, templates / generics, and reflection are different enough between C++ & C# to make porting any non-trivial application a complicated endeavor.  (although C++11 makes it a little easier)

Comment: @SLaks so I should try to make my application as trivial as possible, what should I use instead of `event` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What to use **instead of** c# **event** to have code easy to port to c++?

If you are sure what you think about is only related to **event**, then I think you don't need to make any change.

Just write a underlying class for **event**, that reaches your goal.

You might have various ways to do. The first step would be thinkg about CALLBACKs.

Here I provide some code for example, invoking c++ callbacks through P-invoke and wrap into delegates in c#.

Import the callback:

```
[DllImport("devlink.dll")]
static extern int DLRegisterType2CallDeltas(uint pbxh,DLCALLLOGEVENT cb);
```

Define the delegate:

```
public delegate void DLCALLLOGEVENT(uint pbxh, StringBuilder info);
```

Declare the event:

```
public event EventHandler<CallLogEventArgs> CallLogEvent;
```

Wrap the event to call:

```
DLRegisterType2CallDeltas(
    pbxHandle,
    (pbxh, info) => {
        lock(thisLock)
            if(
                default(EventHandler<CallLogEventArgs>)!=CallLogEvent
                &&
                pbxHandle==pbxh
                )
                CallLogEvent(this, new CallLogEventArgs(info));
    }
    );
```

You'd need to do something **reversed/inverted** in c++. But first of all, implement a class for **event** or **delegate** would get you closer to done what you've asked.

Answer (score 2):

Events in .net (C# included) are just an interpretation of the Observer design pattern; any C ++ implementation of this same pattern will have "similar" behavior.

Edit: some quickly googled-for links on topic:

- [A SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225162/observer-design-pattern-in-c)
- [Observer pattern in C++ on The Tutorial Site](http://login2win.blogspot.com/2008/05/c-observer-patterm.html)
- [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/888/Applying-Observer-Pattern-in-C-Applications)

Answer (score 0):

You can quite easily implement events in C++11 with lambdas and std::function.

Comment: would it be a good idea? will you do that from scratch? or this is just a "workaround" of c# porting problem? probably I should just use in C# different pattern which is "natural" for c++?

Comment: @javapowered: No; don't try to force C++ patterns in C#.  You'll just end up writing a horrible mess.

Comment: so I have to have either a horrible mess or horrible c# to c++ migrate, right? the question is what is more horrible.

Comment: You should not migrate C# solutions into C++ nor import C++ solutions into C#. You have to accept, that you'll have to rewrite portions (possibly quite big) of your code. BTW, why don't you write the code from beginning in C++ and then call it from within C# by P/Invoke?

Comment: @Spook i just refactoring existent c# code. but after a while i will rewrite it to c++. i can not rewrite it right now. the question is if I should use `event` or I should use something else to make my code more easy to rewrite

Comment: You'll have to write some things from scratch anyway. So this is a question, whether use easily events in C# and then rewrite them from scratch in C++ or write an event framework in C# mimicking one you'll implement in C++ later anyway and then rewrite it from C# to C++. Which one sounds better? :) And this concerns every aspect of language you are referring to.

Comment: @Spook I was thinking I should use something completely different that can substitute `event`. I don't know what. Probably inheritance somehow, probably some well-known design pattern....

Comment: well probably i can replace `event` with `boost:signal` and that's it? as suggested above.

Comment: You can. You can also quite easily write event system very similar to one available in C# using lambdas and std::function.

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt you could always fall right back to the Windows API. Check out events etc. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686364(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I haven't written c++ for several years but used these quite happily then. In the .net world there are wrappers in System.Threading, but under the hood they're the same thing.

Obviously I'm assuming here that your target is (and will remain) Windows. This is a bit of a sledgehammer approach but I think it would be foolproof.